# MySQL inserts stop from Python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to pull records from the a database, do some processing on one of the fields, then insert the data back into the database. However, I notice that the script stops after one successful insert, even though there are many more records beyond what is inserted into the database.

```
cur = db.cursor()
# Pull records from the database, process each one, and store back into the database
SQLQuery = """SELECT * FROM cybersecurity4.hackhoundposts"""
cur.execute(SQLQuery)
for row in cur:
    postID = row[0]
    threadID = row[1]
    authorID = row[2]
    url = row[3]
    subforum = row[4]
    threadTitle = row[5]
    authorName = row[6]
    postDateTime = row[7]
    postSequence = row[8]
    flatcontent = row[9]
    userTitle = row[11]
    hasAttachment = row[12]

    print (postID)

# #process the flatcontent
    flatcontent = rmvSpecialCharsandCamelCase(flatcontent)

# insert into the database
    try:
        string = """INSERT INTO cybersecurity4.cleanedhackhoundposts
                 (postid, threadid, authorid, URL, subforum, threadTitle, authorName, postdatetime, postSequence, flatcontent, usertitle, hasattachment)
                VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');""" %  \
             (postID ,threadID,authorID,url,subforum,threadTitle,authorName,postDateTime,postSequence,flatcontent,userTitle,hasAttachment)
        print (string)
        cur.execute(string)
        print ("Successfully inserted post " + str(postID))
    except:
        int("Failed to insert post" + str(postID))
```

Comment: It's a really bad practice to just do `except`. Try changing it to specific exception that may happen here.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your code, you have nothing repeating the insertion, so you are retrieving N records, but only inserting 1 record. Some sudo code of what you need to achieve is.

```
While(cursor hasnext):
    select row

    manipulate

    insert
```

You are close to the result, but missing the last steps.

Edit: 
You can not insert ids on the same id as you select you must let the db handle the id or simply update the row. So removing id from the insert query would probably fix the problem. Next time also check the database log it tells alot.

Comment: I'm sorry that was a copying mistake, everything is already inside of the loop.

Comment: Code does not fail with the except block, it just stops after successfully inserting in one record. I tried it with both a for loop and a while loop.

Comment: And you are sure the for looping is running more then once?

Comment: Yes, when I do simple tasks like just printing postID (which has one for each record), it prints out each postID for all of the records. But when I try to insert back into the DB, like what I am trying to do, there is no luck.

Comment: I am inserting the processed records into a new table, separate from the one I was pulling the data from.

Comment: My fault, I think your next step is to find the db log